# How can I instantiate multiple timer jobs with differing names

Tags: timer-jobs

I have created a timer job in VS and want to instantiate a number of times so I can have differing schedules. How can I do this.

Answer (score 0):

Build your timer job solution and look for ".wsp" file being generated. Now deploy the ".wsp" file usually u do for every SP 2010 solution using Add-SPSolution and Install-SPSolution command. If your solution is intended for MOSS 2007, use

Now to schedule your timer job, go to Central Admin 2010 -> Monitoring -> Timer Jobs -> Review Job Definitions, now find your file and click on it. This will open Edit Timer Job window where you can schedule your timer job.

Check out this it may help you: http://dotnetfinder.wordpress.com/2010/07/24/creatingcustomsharepointtimerjob2010/
[http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/sharepoint/SharePoint-2010-Custom 416cd3a1/view/SourceCode#content](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/sharepoint/SharePoint-2010-Custom-416cd3a1/view/SourceCode#content)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi - I cant see the reply button, using comment. At which point can I give the timer job a differnt name, so it instantiates a new copy. i.e. Multiple copies of same timer jos ?